TwoSum - Leetcode - Any Alternate way
I am learning how to write code logic and tried with this logic and it worked.

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices
of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and
you may not use the same element twice.
You can return the answer in any order.
Example 1:
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Explanation: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].

Example 2:
Input: nums = [3,2,4], target = 6
Output: [1,2]

Example 3:
Input: nums = [3,3], target = 6
Output: [0,1]


My code:
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:

        dt = {}

        for i,val in enumerate(nums):
            diff = target - val
            if diff not in dt:
                dt[val] = i
            else:
                return dt[diff],i

Is there any other way it can be implemented apart from dictionary concept?

Literally tens of thousands of solutions are posted right there on LeetCode. Are you saying you couldn't find any different way among them?

There are lots of solutions that LeetCode users have posted in the "Solutions" section. Assuming  a hashmap/hashset addition operation has O(1) amortised complexity, that is the way to go. Other submitted solutions use diverse methods, including:

brute force (looking at all pairs)
sort the input (with some sort algorithm, native or not), and apply a two pointer/index approach to compare the relevant pairs
binary search tree (potentially self-balancing) to replace the hashmap/set approaches

I found one that uses two binary heaps. Akin to that latter approach, you could use a single binary heap:
If for a moment we assume that the target is 0, we could key the heap entries by the absolute value of the input values, and if we then pop elements from that heap and find two consecutive popped values that have the same absolute value, but opposite original value, then we have found the pair of interest.
To translate a problem with a non-zero target, map the input values to values that have half of the target subtracted from them, or -- to keep with integer values -- double that.
Here is an implementation:
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        heap = [(abs(x := val * 2 - target), x, i) for i, val in enumerate(nums)]
        heapq.heapify(heap)
        prev = heapq.heappop(heap)
        curr = heapq.heappop(heap)
        while prev[1] != -curr[1]:
            prev = curr
            curr = heapq.heappop(heap)
        return [prev[2], curr[2]]

I think at the time of writing, this single-binary-heap algorithm has not yet been posted in the "solutions" section on LeetCode, although it is hard to search it for only heap-based implementations.
If mutation of the original list is allowed, you can of course turn nums into that heap instead of allocating a new list.
